# To list out the hierarchy in depth on employees table using CTE

Tags: oracle, common-table-expression

I am trying to find the hierarchy in the employees table using a CTE Query, using the below query.

```
WITH MANAGERS
    (EMPID, 
     ENAME,
     MID,
     MNAME,
     DEPTH)
AS
(
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID AS EMPID,
       FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME AS ENAME,
       MANAGER_ID AS MID,
       FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME AS MNAME,
       0
    FROM EMPLOYEES 
    WHERE MANAGER_ID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID AS EMPID,
       EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME||' '||EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME AS ENAME,
       EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID AS MID,
       MANAGERS.MNAME,
       MANAGERS.DEPTH+1 
    FROM EMPLOYEES JOIN MANAGERS
    ON EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID=MANAGERS.EMPID
)
SELECT * FROM MANAGERS
ORDER BY DEPTH;
```

But in the result "Steven King" repeats as manager_name for all the records, instead of the respective manager name. Can someone help me identify the error in my SQL?

Thanks in advance
Helina

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining "back" to the employees table to get the manager name. But when you join back, you are now looking at that manager as an employee, so it is the employee name not the manager name column you want

```
SQL> WITH MANAGERS
  2      (EMPID,
  3       ENAME,
  4       MID,
  5       MNAME,
  6       DEPTH)
  7  AS
  8  (
  9  SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID AS EMPID,
 10         FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME AS ENAME,
 11         MANAGER_ID AS MID,
 12         FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME AS MNAME,
 13         0
 14      FROM EMPLOYEES
 15      WHERE MANAGER_ID IS NULL
 16  UNION ALL
 17  SELECT EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID AS EMPID,
 18         EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME||' '||EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME AS ENAME,
 19         EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID AS MID,
 20         MANAGERS.ENAME,
 21         MANAGERS.DEPTH+1
 22      FROM EMPLOYEES JOIN MANAGERS
 23      ON EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID=MANAGERS.EMPID
 24  )
 25  SELECT * FROM MANAGERS
 26  ORDER BY DEPTH;

     EMPID ENAME                                                 MID MNAME                                               DEPTH
---------- ---------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------- ----------
       100 Steven King                                               Steven King                                             0
       101 Neena Kochhar                                         100 Steven King                                             1
       102 Lex De Haan                                           100 Steven King                                             1
       114 Den Raphaely                                          100 Steven King                                             1
       120 Matthew Weiss                                         100 Steven King                                             1
       121 Adam Fripp                                            100 Steven King                                             1
       122 Payam Kaufling                                        100 Steven King                                             1
       123 Shanta Vollman                                        100 Steven King                                             1
       124 Kevin Mourgos                                         100 Steven King                                             1
       145 John Russell                                          100 Steven King                                             1
       146 Karen Partners                                        100 Steven King                                             1
       147 Alberto Errazuriz                                     100 Steven King                                             1
       148 Gerald Cambrault                                      100 Steven King                                             1
       149 Eleni Zlotkey                                         100 Steven King                                             1
       201 Michael Hartstein                                     100 Steven King                                             1
       202 Pat Fay                                               201 Michael Hartstein                                       2
       200 Jennifer Whalen                                       101 Neena Kochhar                                           2
       203 Susan Mavris                                          101 Neena Kochhar                                           2
       204 Hermann Baer                                          101 Neena Kochhar                                           2
       205 Shelley Higgins                                       101 Neena Kochhar                                           2
       108 Nancy Greenberg                                       101 Neena Kochhar                                           2
       103 Alexander Hunold                                      102 Lex De Haan                                             2
       115 Alexander Khoo                                        114 Den Raphaely                                            2
       116 Shelli Baida                                          114 Den Raphaely                                            2
       117 Sigal Tobias                                          114 Den Raphaely                                            2
       118 Guy Himuro                                            114 Den Raphaely                                            2
       119 Karen Colmenares                                      114 Den Raphaely                                            2
       125 Julia Nayer                                           120 Matthew Weiss                                           2
       126 Irene Mikkilineni                                     120 Matthew Weiss                                           2
       127 James Landry                                          120 Matthew Weiss                                           2
       128 Steven Markle                                         120 Matthew Weiss                                           2
       180 Winston Taylor                                        120 Matthew Weiss                                           2
       181 Jean Fleaur                                           120 Matthew Weiss                                           2
       182 Martha Sullivan                                       120 Matthew Weiss                                           2
       183 Girard Geoni                                          120 Matthew Weiss                                           2
       129 Laura Bissot                                          121 Adam Fripp                                              2
       130 Mozhe Atkinson                                        121 Adam Fripp                                              2
       131 James Marlow                                          121 Adam Fripp                                              2
       132 TJ Olson                                              121 Adam Fripp                                              2
       184 Nandita Sarchand                                      121 Adam Fripp                                              2
       185 Alexis Bull                                           121 Adam Fripp                                              2
       186 Julia Dellinger                                       121 Adam Fripp                                              2
       187 Anthony Cabrio                                        121 Adam Fripp                                              2
       133 Jason Mallin                                          122 Payam Kaufling                                          2
       134 Michael Rogers                                        122 Payam Kaufling                                          2
       135 Ki Gee                                                122 Payam Kaufling                                          2
       136 Hazel Philtanker                                      122 Payam Kaufling                                          2
       188 Kelly Chung                                           122 Payam Kaufling                                          2
       189 Jennifer Dilly                                        122 Payam Kaufling                                          2
       190 Timothy Gates                                         122 Payam Kaufling                                          2
       191 Randall Perkins                                       122 Payam Kaufling                                          2
       137 Renske Ladwig                                         123 Shanta Vollman                                          2
       138 Stephen Stiles                                        123 Shanta Vollman                                          2
       139 John Seo                                              123 Shanta Vollman                                          2
       140 Joshua Patel                                          123 Shanta Vollman                                          2
       192 Sarah Bell                                            123 Shanta Vollman                                          2
       193 Britney Everett                                       123 Shanta Vollman                                          2
       194 Samuel McCain                                         123 Shanta Vollman                                          2
       195 Vance Jones                                           123 Shanta Vollman                                          2
       198 Donald OConnell                                       124 Kevin Mourgos                                           2
       199 Douglas Grant                                         124 Kevin Mourgos                                           2
       141 Trenna Rajs                                           124 Kevin Mourgos                                           2
       142 Curtis Davies                                         124 Kevin Mourgos                                           2
       143 Randall Matos                                         124 Kevin Mourgos                                           2
       144 Peter Vargas                                          124 Kevin Mourgos                                           2
       196 Alana Walsh                                           124 Kevin Mourgos                                           2
       197 Kevin Feeney                                          124 Kevin Mourgos                                           2
       150 Peter Tucker                                          145 John Russell                                            2
       151 David Bernstein                                       145 John Russell                                            2
       152 Peter Hall                                            145 John Russell                                            2
       153 Christopher Olsen                                     145 John Russell                                            2
       154 Nanette Cambrault                                     145 John Russell                                            2
       155 Oliver Tuvault                                        145 John Russell                                            2
       156 Janette King                                          146 Karen Partners                                          2
       157 Patrick Sully                                         146 Karen Partners                                          2
       158 Allan McEwen                                          146 Karen Partners                                          2
       159 Lindsey Smith                                         146 Karen Partners                                          2
       160 Louise Doran                                          146 Karen Partners                                          2
       161 Sarath Sewall                                         146 Karen Partners                                          2
       162 Clara Vishney                                         147 Alberto Errazuriz                                       2
       163 Danielle Greene                                       147 Alberto Errazuriz                                       2
       164 Mattea Marvins                                        147 Alberto Errazuriz                                       2
       165 David Lee                                             147 Alberto Errazuriz                                       2
       166 Sundar Ande                                           147 Alberto Errazuriz                                       2
       167 Amit Banda                                            147 Alberto Errazuriz                                       2
       168 Lisa Ozer                                             148 Gerald Cambrault                                        2
       169 Harrison Bloom                                        148 Gerald Cambrault                                        2
       170 Tayler Fox                                            148 Gerald Cambrault                                        2
       171 William Smith                                         148 Gerald Cambrault                                        2
       172 Elizabeth Bates                                       148 Gerald Cambrault                                        2
       173 Sundita Kumar                                         148 Gerald Cambrault                                        2
       174 Ellen Abel                                            149 Eleni Zlotkey                                           2
       175 Alyssa Hutton                                         149 Eleni Zlotkey                                           2
       176 Jonathon Taylor                                       149 Eleni Zlotkey                                           2
       177 Jack Livingston                                       149 Eleni Zlotkey                                           2
       178 Kimberely Grant                                       149 Eleni Zlotkey                                           2
       179 Charles Johnson                                       149 Eleni Zlotkey                                           2
       206 William Gietz                                         205 Shelley Higgins                                         3
       109 Daniel Faviet                                         108 Nancy Greenberg                                         3
       110 John Chen                                             108 Nancy Greenberg                                         3
       111 Ismael Sciarra                                        108 Nancy Greenberg                                         3
       107 Diana Lorentz                                         103 Alexander Hunold                                        3
       113 Luis Popp                                             108 Nancy Greenberg                                         3
       104 Bruce Ernst                                           103 Alexander Hunold                                        3
       105 David Austin                                          103 Alexander Hunold                                        3
       106 Valli Pataballa                                       103 Alexander Hunold                                        3
       112 Jose Manuel Urman                                     108 Nancy Greenberg                                         3

107 rows selected.
```